# about download a file by java drive api

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I use the "get" method from java drive api, and I can get the inputstream. but I cannt open the file when I use the inputstream to creat it. It likes the file is broken.

```
private static String fileurl = "C:\\googletest\\drive\\";

public static void newFile(String filetitle, InputStream stream) throws IOException {
    String filepath = fileurl + filetitle;      
    BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream=new BufferedInputStream(stream);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferedInputStream.available()];


    File file = new File(filepath);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();

        BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filepath));
          while( bufferedInputStream.read(buffer) != -1) { 
              bufferedOutputStream.write(buffer);
      }  
          bufferedOutputStream.flush();
          bufferedOutputStream.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What the exception do you get?

Comment: *"java drive api"*  What is that, exactly?

Comment: `private static String fileurl = "C:\\googletest\\drive\\";`  That attribute name is misleading, since the content in no way represents an URL.  It might be a valid file path.

Comment: no exception, it create file successfully, but i cannt open the file.

Comment: Tip:  Add @CAMOBAP (or whoever) to notify them of a new comment.

Comment: @CAMOBAP a example, I download a pdf file, and create it successfully, the file size looks like well, but it shows something problem when I open it...

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson ok~ thanks~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `C:\googletest\drive\` is not a URL.  It is a file system pathname.

Next, the following probably does not do what you think it does:

```
  byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferedInputStream.available()];
```

The problem is that the `available()` call can return zero ... for a non-empty stream.  The value returned by `available()` is an *estimate* of how many bytes that are currently available to read ... right now.  That is not necessarily the stream length ... or anything related to it.  And indeed the device drivers for some devices *consistently* return zero, even when there is data to be read.

Finally, this is wrong:

```
   while( bufferedInputStream.read(buffer) != -1) { 
          bufferedOutputStream.write(buffer);
```

You are assuming that `read` returning `-1` means that it *filled* the buffer.  That is not so.  Any one of the `read` calls could return with a partly full buffer.  But then you write the entire buffer contents to the output stream ... including "junk" from previous reads.

---

Either or both of the 2nd and 3rd problems could lead to file corruption.  In fact, the third one is *likely* to.

Comment: thanks~ I fix it, and I can open the file well~
   int available = -1;
   while ((available=bufferedInputStream.read(buffer))>0) {
    bufferedOutputStream.write(buffer,0,available);
   }

Comment: OK ... but I don't think 'available' is a good name for that variable, because it hints at the value returned by the `available()` method.  I'd call it `bytesRead` or something like that.